# Can't get Entity from Datastore by Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to access get the Entity by the Key, But I'm getting the exception every time I try do get it.

```
    datastore.put(en);
    String key = en.getKey();
```

Then key is sent to the other servlet as String like 4644337115725824. And when I'm trying to get Entity by this code

```
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("User", req.getParameter("key"));
    Entity en = datastore.get(key);
```

On the last line I have an EntityNotFoundException and 'No entity was found matching the key: User("4644337115725824")'
What's wrong?

Comment: Make sure the key matches with the key in the Datastore, EntityNotFoundException arises only when there is no match found in the datastore

Comment: `Entity.getKey()` returns a `Key`, not a `String`, so if you want to get the ID from the Key to pass to your other servlet, you need to call `Key.getID()` (for a `Long` ID) or `Key.getName()` for a `String` ID. What do you see in the datastore viewer for this entity?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that when key is sent, the Key.getID() is called, and only ID is sent. But I think, there is something wrong with the String between (), because Key.toString() returns Kind(number), not Kind("number") as you can see in the Exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a serialization/deserialization problem for the key. To serialize a key into a websafe String, use [KeyFactory.keyToString(key)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#keyToString(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key)):

```
Key key = entity.getKey();
String serializedKey = KeyFactory.keyToString(key);
```

Later on, when you want to deserialize the key on the other servlet, you can use [KeyFactory.stringToKey(string)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#stringToKey(java.lang.String)):

```
Key deserializedKey = KeyFactory.stringToKey(serializedKey);
Entity en = datastore.get(deserializedKey);
```